# How to retain retrieved data using PHP or jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have an extract PHP script below (useracc-test.php). After I login via login.php, I will be brought into user page(useracc-test.php). Inside useracc-test.php, I can view my personal data (id, name, username, telno). But when I press a  submit button, the retrieved data (id, name, username, telno) disappears. Because in the same page, I also have an insert form. But first of all, How do I retain the retrieved data(the personal data displayed) everytime I press the submit button? Please help. I tried "print", but It is only suitable when I enter a data manually in the insert form. BUt i cannot apply it to the retrieved data (personal data). I downloaded jQuery and learned about it but still cannot understand completely how to use it. Is there a way if I can use PHP to retain data? I tried all the examples from the internet several days, I cannot find  or understand a suitable solution.Im losing my mind. Please help.

The data below- id, name, username, telno keeps disappearing everytime i press submit. How to retain it?.

```
       <?php

    //useracc-test.php

    //start session
    session_start();



    require 'connect-test.php'; 




    if(isset($_POST['username'])){

        $userName = $_POST['username'];
        $query = "SELECT id, name, username, telno FROM users WHERE username = ?";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $userName);
        $stmt->execute();
        $res = $stmt->get_result(); 
        $row = $res->fetch_array();
        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
        $_SESSION['telno'] = $row['telno'];
    }
    ?>



    <html>
    <head>    


</head>
    <body>
    <div id="apDiv3">
    <div id="TabbedPanels1" class="TabbedPanels">
      <ul class="TabbedPanelsTabGroup">
        <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0">Tab 1</li>
        <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0">Tab 2</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="TabbedPanelsContentGroup">
        <div class="TabbedPanelsContent">
          <p>


          </p>

          <?php
        echo $_SESSION['id']."<br/>";
        echo $_SESSION['name']."<br/>";
        echo $_SESSION['username']."<br/>";
        echo $_SESSION['telno']."<br/>";
    ?>



            <?php



     if(isset($_POST['submit']))

       {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $name2 = $_POST['name2'];
        $color2 = $_POST['color2'];
        $hobby2 = $_POST['hobby2'];



        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO useradvert (id,name2,color2,hobby2) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("isss",$id,$name2,$color2,$hobby2);
        $stmt->execute();

       // $stmt->close();
       // $conn->close();
       } 


        ?>   







          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="TabbedPanelsContent">
          <form name="form2" method="post" action="useracc-test.php">
            <p>&nbsp;</p>



                 <p>id :        
                   <label for="id"></label>
                   <input name="id" type="text" id="id" value="<?php echo  htmlspecialchars 
                   ($row['id']); ?>" >

                 </p>
            <p>name :
              <input type="text" name="name2" id="name2">
            </p>
            <p>color2 :
              <input type="text" name="color2" id="color2">
            </p>
            <p>hobby2 :
              <input type="text" name="hobby2" id="hobby2">
            </p>
            <p>
              <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
            </p>
          </form>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>    
      <script type="text/javascript">
    var TabbedPanels1 = new Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels("TabbedPanels1");
      </script>

    <?php unset($_SESSION); 
    session_destroy(); ?>
    </body>
                   </html>
```

Comment: hard to say without knowing where your inputs are/how POST arrays are associated with those (lots of code missing here). check for errors if any and check the developer console.

Comment: Your issue lies with `$userName= isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';`. You are only giving `$userName` a value if you have posted an input named `username`. Since you are already using `session_start();`, you could save `$_POST['username']` to a `$_SESSION` variable, and then check for that when `$_POST['username']` is not set. ie. `if(isset($_POST['username']))  $_SESSION['userName'] = $_POST['username']; $userName= isset($_SESSION['userName']) ? $_SESSION['userName']: (isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '');`

Comment: HI.. thank u all for the reply.. hi SamyQc...I tried your suggestions.. but it seems the data keeps disappears everytime I press submit. The (id, name, username and telno) keeps disappearing. Why is it?

Comment: @LindaMay if you want to comment to someone specific, either post your comment on their answer, or add a @ before their name.

Comment: Sorry @Sean. I apologise. noted and tqs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just after the fetch array, you should assign the result in a $_SESSION variable

```
$_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
$_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
$_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
$_SESSION['telno'] = $row['telno'];
```

Your $_SESSION variable will be available in each page that there is a session_start().

You can flush the $_SESSION variable when the user logout like this :

```
unset($_SESSION); 
session_destroy();
```

To print the results, you can do it like this :

```
<?php
    echo $_SESSION['id']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['name']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['username']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['telno']."<br/>";
<?
```

EDIT : Change the top of your code like this. Each time you were clicking on ''SUBMIT'', the query was executed again, but since this time $_POST['username'] wasn't set, you were assigning an empty string into your $username variable

```
<?php

//useracc-test.php

//start session
session_start();

require 'connect-test.php';

if(isset($_POST['username'])){

    $userName = $_POST['username'];
    $query = "SELECT id, name, username, telno FROM users WHERE username = ?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $userName);
    $stmt->execute();
    $res = $stmt->get_result(); 
    $row = $res->fetch_array();
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
    $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
    $_SESSION['telno'] = $row['telno'];
}
?>
```

Comment: see the [OP's comment to you here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34534871/how-to-retain-retrieved-data-using-php-or-jquery#comment56812016_34534871)

Comment: @Linda May , I think it is because you are assigning an empty value at your $username variable the second time the page is loaded, and you're doing the query but this time with username = "". I'll edit my answer for you.

Comment: Hi, i tried your suggestion. I appreciate your help and tq. But it still empty. Will it help if i post my entire script?

Comment: You tried with my last edit ? If it doesn't work, yes you could post your whole code.

Comment: Thanks @SamyQc. I tried the above. But i got error. Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\xampp\htdocs\eventsite\useracc-test.php on line 40

Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\xampp\htdocs\eventsite\useracc-test.php on line 41

Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\xampp\htdocs\eventsite\useracc-test.php on line 42

Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\xampp\htdocs\eventsite\useracc-test.php on line 43

Comment: this is line 40-43: $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
$_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
$_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
$_SESSION['telno'] = $row['telno'];

Comment: Are you assigning your value just after the fetch_array()? I re-edited my post to show you where you should assign it to your session variable

Comment: Yes,  @SamyQc. Thank you I appreciate. But now I got new error. Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\eventsite\useracc-test.php on line 94


Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\eventsite\useracc-test.php on line 95


Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\eventsite\useracc-test.php on line 96


Notice: Undefined index: telno in C:\xampp\htdocs\eventsite\useracc-test.php on line 97

Comment: Line 94-97:  <?php
    echo $_SESSION['id']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['name']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['username']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['telno']."<br/>";
?>

Comment: This error is because you have nothing assigned in your $_SESSION variable (looks like you are never getting in the  IF(isset()) statement. Go back a page and login again, and try to check if you get something in your $_POST['username'] variable.  To check this, you can do a <?php echo $_POST['username'];  ?>  at the top of useracc-test.php, go back a page and login

Comment: @LindaMay remove the 

unset($_SESSION); 
session_destroy(); 

It is only to log out, do a special button for this later or something. That's why you have nothing in your $_SESSION variable and getting the last error you said.

Comment: I tried what u told me. I put <?php echo $_POST['username']; ?> at the top of useracc-test.php. It just display the username. BUt after i press submit button, it keeps giving undefined index error.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\eventsite\useracc-test.php on line 11 Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\eventsite\useracc-test.php on line 95


Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\eventsite\useracc-test.php on line 96


Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\eventsite\useracc-test.php on line 97


Notice: Undefined index: telno in C:\xampp\htdocs\eventsite\useracc-test.php on line 98

Comment: sorry @Samy Qc. I appreciate your help. Im really sorry for troubling you. I'm also exhausted for several days. I've been trying this since morning..its midnight now at my place. I still can't make it work.

Comment: wow.. i removed the logout session as you told me. now it works fine.. Thanks @SamyQc. God bless you. Finally at last I can sleep tonight. thank u so much.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help you :).

Answer (score 0):

It wont retain because the username needed for your sql was probably posted from the login form. Once you refresh the page from your `useracc-test.php` the posted data is nowhere to be found because it was retrieve from login.php

now what you can do is use `SESSIONS`

`session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
isset($_SESSION['username']) ? $id = $_SESSION['username'] : false;`

`$_SESSION` can be used anywhere as long as there is `session_start()`

Comment: Hi.. tqs John Pangilinan. I tried your suggestion, but this time, after I login, there was no data at all. my id, name, username and telno is blank. any reason?. I appreciate your help @John Pangilinan and sorry for troubling you.

Comment: Will it help if i post my entire script?